# How to reload connected users page on a real-time chat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, socket.io

A real-time chat
The following code works fine
New message is inserted into all connected users interface

```
const socket = io();

socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    apan.prepend(msg);
});

btnsend.on('click', function(){
    var str = bstory.text().trim();
    socket.emit('chat message', str);
    // ajax code for storing new message into database and reload the sender's page
});
```

Now I don't want to insert the new message into users interface
I just want to reload their chat page

Here is my try

```
socket.on('reload', function() {
    location.reload();
});

btnsend.on('click', function(){
    var str = bstory.text().trim();
    // ajax code for storing new message into database and reload the sender's page
    socket.emit('reload');
});
```

It doesn't work. User's pages are not reloaded